# Spring Shell components don't show up

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-shell, jline, jline3

I'm trying to use the Spring Shell built-in components StringInput, PathInput, ConfirmationInput, SingleSelect and MultiSelect. Each time I try and use one of these by executing the run() method they inherit from AbstractComponent nothing shows up and the result is simply null.
I've ran through the run method with a debugger and the problem seems to be that my getTerminal() call in the constructor of the component always returns a DumbTerminal.

Here is the code I used from the documentation:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.shell.component.StringInput;
import org.springframework.shell.component.StringInput.StringInputContext;
import org.springframework.shell.standard.AbstractShellComponent;
import org.springframework.shell.standard.ShellComponent;
import org.springframework.shell.standard.ShellMethod;

@ShellComponent
public class ComponentCommands extends AbstractShellComponent {

    @ShellMethod(key = "component string", value = "String input", group = "Components")
    public String stringInput(boolean mask) {
        StringInput component = new StringInput(getTerminal(), "Enter value", "myvalue");
        component.setResourceLoader(getResourceLoader());
        component.setTemplateExecutor(getTemplateExecutor());
        if (mask) {
            component.setMaskCharater('*');
        }
        StringInputContext context = component.run(StringInputContext.empty());
        return "Got value " + context.getResultValue();
    }
}
```

As my main method I used the normal spring boot application:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
   }

}
```

If I replace the getTerminal() like the following code, a prompt does show up but the text I type overwrites the prompt and I can't press enter.

```
Terminal terminal = TerminalBuilder.builder()
        .system(false)
        .streams(System.in, System.out)
        .build();
StringInput component = new StringInput(terminal, "Enter value", "myvalue");
```

I've also tried running the program from an actual terminal instead of my IDE but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was using the internal IntelliJ terminal instead of a proper one.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem too when building and running from IntelliJ. (Java 8 and Spring 2.7.13)
But in my experience, running from IntelliJ and using its internal Console was not the root cause. The IntelliJ's Console still can be used, and commands added with ShellComponent and ShellMethod annotations are scanned and work fine but only after the project was built from the command line, for example, in my case with Maven:

```
aws-fsx-s3-poc\>mvnw clean package -DskipTests
```

After that, it can be run from cmd or even from IntelliJ console.

Note: tests must be skipped, came across a warning on a Spring website and experienced that too - tests do go into an endless loop.

```
@ShellComponent
public class ShellCLI {
    @ShellMethod(value = "Test command")
    public String echo(@ShellOption({"-N", "--name"}) String input) {
        return "Entered: " + input;
    }
}
```